# Copy-Item works for IP address, not Computer Name

Tags: powershell, copy-item

The following code will copy files to remote_computer if I use its IP address 10.10.10.10

```
$j = "remote_computer"

New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\$j\share -Credential $credentials -ErrorAction Stop 

Copy-Item -Path D:\ps_*able.ps1 -Destination \\10.10.10.10\share

Remove-PSDrive -name Z
```

This script will NOT copy over files if I use Z, the psdrive

```
$j = "remote_computer"

New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\$j\share -Credential $credentials -ErrorAction Stop 

Copy-Item -Path D:\ps_*able.ps1 -Destination Z

Remove-PSDrive -name Z
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Z" is not a valid path

```
Copy-Item -Path D:\ps_*able.ps1 -Destination Z:\
```

Comment: I tried, "Z:\"and     `\\$j\share`, and even `\\remote_ip\share` but no luck

Comment: so you tried just z:\ by itself? your formatting did not come out correctly there. If you are, and it is not working what error are you getting? It sounds like new-psdrive is not actually mapping anything then.

Comment: yes, z:\ by itself. The output for New-PSDrive shows name `Z` and Root `\\remote_ip\share` ... and even if I don't use Z:\, but instead use the computer name, or a variable that holds the computer name, `Copy-Item` doesn't work

Comment: Can you navigate to that unc path in file explorer? Maybe the credentials you are using don't have write permission?